# Setting Angular CLI generate defaults

Tags: angular-cli

All of my components follow the same structure:

`ng g component componentName --skip-import --s true`

Those two flags will always be used when generating a component. I would like to be able to this without defining the flags every time:

`ng g component componentName`

I'm having a hard time figuring out if there is a place to configure `generate` defaults or if I need to create my own schema. Has anyone else tried doing this before?

I've tried looking at the Angular Docs, mainly for `generate` and `config`(https://angular.io/cli/config) but it's unclear if I can do this.

Comment: something like `ng config schematics.@schematics/angular.component.inlineTemplate true`?

Comment: This is exactly what I was wanting. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: As stated by @ABOS you can use that command, and look into more options to set here `appdata/roaming/npm/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json`.

Comment: @ABOS, it sets the value for one project, not as a global setting..

Comment: @SachinGupta I only wanted it on a project level. I work on multiple projects and not all of them are configured the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try something like,

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular.component.inlineTemplate true
```

Adding `-g` to apply this globally.

You can also specify it in angular.json in your project settings,

```
"schematics": {
 "@schematics/angular": {
   "component": {
     "inlineTemplate": true
   }
 }
}
```

The local settings will override global settings, if exists.